# Custom table of contents layout

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to achieve the following layout of the table of contents

[image]

But I'm a little lost on how to use the `titlesec` package, because I do not know if this package is really for editing the table of contents or just for the titles...

I appreciate your help

Current advances:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.7cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hrulefill}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{chap:intro}
Lorem 

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:lorem}

Pellentesque

\subsection{Ipsum}
\label{sec:intro:ipsum}

Etiam
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: A few remarks: 1) Please embed your document as an image. I'm sure you'll understand people will be hesitant to download a pdf file of a total stranger. 2) You can check out what `titlesec` does in its documentation: http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlesec 3) I haven't done a loft of ToC modification, but I think [`tocloft`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft) is a popular package for that. I suggest you check that out, try to achieve your layout and if there's _something specific_ you can't figure out, you're more than welcome to come back and ask about it.

Comment: Should the format for the title apply to all chapters or just to the Table of Contents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one possible option: the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package was used to format the title for unnumbered sections; the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package was used to format the section entries in the ToC (only change was to typeset chapter entries in `\normalfont`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the OP didn't provide any information regarding the formatting for titles of numbered chapters, my example code included a provisional definition in this case.

As a side note, I used that you need roman numbering for the frontmatter part of your document and then arabic numbering in the mainmatter part: this suggests that switching to the `book` document class might be a sensible choice, since now you can use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter` which will give you some automatic formatting for page numbering (amongst other things); I also used the [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) package to easily include into the ToC entries for the LoF and LoT :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{}{\hfill\rule{.7\textwidth}{3pt}}{0pt}
{\hspace*{.3\textwidth}\huge\bfseries}[\addvspace{-1pt}]

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I change the document class to report, it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks anyway, you have point me in a good direction :D

Comment: @aljndrrr: I edited my answer to use report.

Comment: @aljndrrr in fact, I've just updated my answer again suggestiong you to use `book` instead of `report` and providing the corresponding code.

Comment: Thank you @gonzalo-medina this is what I was looking for

Comment: when i do this, it automatically generates pages with each chapter but I have no idea how to edit them...