# Custom page numbering in Latex Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, page-numbering

I want to add custom page numbers in Tabel of Contents in LaTeX.
In front of section in TOC page number should be like

Chapter 1 Introduction ............................ 1 - 20

here 1 is page number where this Introduction starts and ends on pg 20
I various posts to format page number in TOC **[Custom page numbering display in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307671/custom-page-numbering-display-in-table-of-contents)** which is similar to my requirement, just the user want some different customization. For the this post, **[esdd user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43317/esdd)**  has given the solution using KOMA-Script to customize the TOC, but it gives the pages in which the chapter title is, i.e. 1-1.
But I want to customize page nubers in TOC as seen in below figure (1-20).

[image: Updated TOC]

Comment: See if this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145021/chapterwise-page-range-in-the-toc